# yesod-devel/ghcargs.txt: openFile: does not exist

Tags: haskell, yesod

when starting a yesod application (built in a cabal sandbox) I get

```
Yesod devel server. Press ENTER to quit
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring my-application-0.0.0...
Rebuilding application... (using cabal)
yesod: yesod-devel/ghcargs.txt: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

I have no idea what's happening - how can I find out? (some `verbose` options to `yesod`?)

I can `cabal install` the application (to the sandbox) and then start the binary, which does nothing (that I can observe). If I start with `strace` I get lots of

```
futex(0x426e07c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 21, NULL) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGVTALRM (Virtual timer expired) @ 0 (0) ---
```

(all of this with ghc-7.8.2, current yesod from hackage, on x86_64 GNU/Linux)